# Confidence Intervals of EMMEANS and EMMEANS contrasts

Tags: r, lsmeans, glmmtmb

I am trying to look at how the effect of a large scale event (Event) impacts my response variable (AnimalActivity) across two regions (Region; A impacted by the event and B not impacted), while taking into account human activity (HumanUse) and season (Season). I used the function GLMMTMB to create a generalized linear mixed effects model where the random effect accounts for multiple sampling events from a single point (SamplingSite) and an offset to account for sampling effort (SamplingEffort).

```r
FinalModel <- glmmTMB(AnimalActivity ~  Region + Season +  Event + 
    HumanUse + HumanUse:Season + Season:Event + Season:Region + 
    Region:Event + Season:Region:Event +
                      offset(log(SamplingEffort)) + (1|SamplingSite),
                    data = Data,
                    ziformula = ~Season,
                    na.action = na.pass,
                    family = nbinom1(link = "log"))
```

- Season - Factor with 3 levels (Spring, Summer, Autumn)
- Event - Factor with 2 levels (Pre-Event, Post-Event)
- Region - Factor with 2 levels (A, B)
- HumanUse - Integer

I want to explore the three-way interaction and have been using the package EMMEANS to do so. Below is what I get when I calculate the emmeans using the type "response". I am only presenting my output with summer for sake of saving space with my question and reporting all three seasons is not really needed.

```r
emm <- emmeans(FinalModel, spec = ~Region:Event|Season, 
    type = "response")
print(emm)

Season = Summer:
 Region    Event      response     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 A         Pre-event     0.920 0.2377 5206   0.5541    1.526
 B         Pre-event     0.885 0.2289 5206   0.5335    1.470
 A         Post-event    0.688 0.1788 5206   0.4136    1.145
 B         Post-event    0.502 0.1315 5206   0.2999    0.839

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

When looking at the results above I assume that there is a significant difference in my response variable between Region B pre-event and region B post-event because there is not overlapping confidence intervals. Following this logic I assume that there is not a significant difference in Region A pre-event and post-event becuase there is overlapping confidence intervals.

In comparison when I use the function contrast I get the below output (Using function confint for confidence intervals).

```r
X <- contrast(emm, method = "pairwise")
confint(X)

Season = Summer:
 contrast                       ratio    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 A Pre-event / B Pre-event      1.039 0.378 5206    0.408     2.65
 A Pre-event / A Post-event     1.336 0.107 5206    1.089     1.64
 A Pre-event / B Post-event     1.834 0.672 5206    0.715     4.70
 B Pre-event / A Post-event     1.287 0.469 5206    0.504     3.29
 B Pre-event / B Post-event     1.766 0.152 5206    1.416     2.20
 A Post-event / B Post-event    1.372 0.504 5206    0.534     3.53
```

The above output are ratio's and because of that I assume that if the confidence intervals do not cross 1 there is a significant difference in the contrast (The p-values obtained by summary(X) suggest my thinking here is correct). Using this logic it appears that both the contrasts **A Pre-event / A Post-event** and **B Pre-event / B Post-event** have significant contrasts. I think that this means there was a significant change in animal activity in both regions comparing before and after the event. Where I get confused is that when looking at the original emmeans the confidence interval for region A pre and region A post appeared to be non-significant. How can these emmeans be not significantly different but then the contrast be significant?

In summary I am just wondering if any one knows how these confidence intervals are calculated and may be able to explain why two emmeans appear to be non significant, however, when you contrast them they result in a significant contrast. I would have assumed that if the emmean values were significant than the contrast would be significant and if the emmean values were not significantly different than the contrast would not be significant.

Comment: By default, the P values for pairwise comparisons are *adjusted* using the Tukey method, whereas the confidence intervals are not. If you do `confint(X, adjust = "tukey")`, you will get comparable results. As is explained in the annotations, the intervals are computed before back-transforming, then the endpoints are back-transformed. With the Tukey adjustment, an appropriate critical value from  the Studentized range distribution is used in place of the t-distribution quantile that is used in the unadjusted ones.